# How can I move a Rigidbody smoothly with touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm developing my first game in 2D with Unity for Android and I'm a beginner with C#.

I want the GameObject to move smoothly when the user controls it with the touch.

In this game the GameObject which is a RigidBody moves constantly along the X-axis, and the user can control the Y-axis with touch control, the touch has to follow the movement with an offset so the GameObject changes Y-axis no matter where the user puts his finger (assuming that it was in the left side of the screen). If the user moves up his finger the GameObject would follow that movement and so on.

In the code I managed to do this but it's rough, when I move just my finger a little bit the GameObject acts like it's jumping and moving several pixels on each frame (and yes, I do the ScreenToWorldPoint), it also moves with more speed than my finger gesture and in an instant leaves the screen.

Here is the entire code but I think my problem is in the moved phase:

```
  case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    rb2D.MovePosition(new Vector3(rb2D.position.x + (speed * Time.deltaTime), TouchToWorld.y - delta_Y, 0f));
                    rb2D.rotation = TouchToWorld.y * 10f;
                    break;
```

I need the object to move as smooth has can be and with rigidbody due the physics.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Touch_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 2f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    private float delta_Y;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(40f * speed * Time.deltaTime, rb2D.velocity.y);
        Vector2 ObjectBoundaries = new Vector2(rb2D.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb2D.position.y, -3f, 3f));

        // Track a single touch as a direction control.
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 tch = touch.position;
            Vector3 TouchToWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(tch);

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    rb2D.MovePosition(new Vector3(rb2D.position.x, rb2D.position.y, 0f));
                    delta_Y = TouchToWorld.y - rb2D.position.y;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Stationary:

                    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(40f * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    rb2D.MovePosition(new Vector3(rb2D.position.x + (speed * Time.deltaTime), TouchToWorld.y - delta_Y, 0f));
                    rb2D.rotation = TouchToWorld.y * 10f;
                    break;               

                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    rb2D.rotation = 0f;
                    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(40f * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
                    break;           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FixedUpdate` calls in unity are spaced out by intervals that can be accessed via `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, not `Time.deltaTime`. The default value for `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is 0.02 seconds which is 50 calls per second, which may be much smaller than `Time.deltaTime`, which may be the source of your excessive movement here. Fix that first, and see if it works.

Comment: @ChaeHoShin the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) clearly recommends that you should rather use `Time.deltaTime` **not** `Time.fixedDeltaTime` also in `FixedUpdate` for reading

Comment: You might be getting your axes wrong. Is your game, 2d, 2.5d or 3d? So according to your explanation, game +x axis is forward, and +y axis is right? Touch coordinates are y is up-down, x-axis is left-right. You are using touch y axis for your left-right which is wrong.

Comment: @derHugo, Time.deltaTime returns Time.fixedDeltaTime when used in FixedUpdate, either way works.

Comment: @AykutKaraca I know .. I just pointed out that this will not be the issue here since the docs even recommend explicitly to not use `fixedDeltaTime` .. it was a response to Chae Ho Shims comment which claimed you should use`fixedDeltaTime` instead of `deltaTime` .. which isn't the case ;)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do both rb.Velocity and rb.MovePosition.  Doing both will conflict with each other.  I think you are seeing it move by the Velocity ammount, and get pulled back to your finger by MovePosition().   Try not setting rb.Velocity when TouchCount > 0;